# How do I wrap a detail row onto multiple lines?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

SQL Server Reporting Services 2008

I have a row with 30 fields. Instead of one row with 30 fields, I want to arrange them so I have three rows of 10 fields each. I created this report using the wizard and the report type is a table (not matrix). How do I do this?

Here is the desired output:

```
Header1   Header2   Header3
Data1     Data2     Data3

Header4   Header5   Header6
Data4     Data5     Data6 

Header7   Header8   Header9
Data7     Data8     Data9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use three details rows (and three header rows if you are using headers). This means adding two more details (innermost) rows, and two more header (outermost) rows. It should look like the following when you're done:

```
HEADER:       Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | ...
HEADER:       Header11| Header12| Header13| ...
HEADER:       Header21| Header22| Header23| ...
GROUP HEADER: Group Name
DETAILS:      Field1  | Field2  | Field3  | ...
DETAILS:      Field11 | Field12 | Field13 | ...
DETAILS:      Field21 | Field22 | Field23 | ...
```

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying but I can't create it in SSRS. I am using headers. I created a new table and can't figure out how to create the multiple headers and details arrangement you have in your answer.

Comment: If you're using the designer, you should be able to right-click on the existing header or details row and do an Insert Row

Comment: I can insert the rows (one for the header and one for the data) but do I then need to manually add the field? Or can select the field from a list and have the header automatically inserted, like the behavior of the default data row?

Comment: Try selecting the field and see if it's smart? If not you'll have to type the header. You could probably copy&paste ten headers at a time from your pre-existing 30-field row though.

Comment: No, the new rows are not smart.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but just in case anyone else is looking, this thread worked well for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/limit-no-of-columns-in-ssrs-matrix-report

I've copied some of it below, in case the link dies:

Step one: copy the following code to the custom code area

```
Dim FlagTable As System.Collections.Hashtable

Dim Flag AS Integer

 Function MyFunc(ByVal NewValue As Object) As Integer

If (FlagTable Is Nothing) Then

FlagTable = New System.Collections.Hashtable

End If

If (NewValue Is Nothing) Then

NewValue = "-"

End If

If (Not FlagTable .Contains(NewValue )) Then

Flag =Flag + 1

FlagTable.Add(NewValue, nothing)

End If

MyFunc = Flag

End Function
```

Step two: Add a list to your report

1. Right-click the list ,and then select Properties.
2. Click Edit details group… button
3. Type in the expression `=Ceiling(Code.MyFunc(Fields!Productname.Value)/2)`

Note:

1) `Fields!Productname.Value` is your column group datafield

2) `2` is the number of the columns you want to display in a row